# How to add "android_asset/www/" to the image's path in the CSS only if app is running in Android?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

So, I'm building a hybrid app using the Ionic framework and AngularJS.
I created a volume slider with a custom style, using the code below:

**style.css**

```
input[type=range] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;    
   height: 9px;
   background-image: url("/img/bar.png");
   border: none;
   width: 280px;

}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   border: none;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;   
   background-image: url("/img/slider.png");

}
```

When I test it in the browser it works fine. But **the problem is:** to run it in Android I have to add "android_asset/www/" in the image path. For all the images that I'm using in the html, I made a function in the js file that detects if the app is running in Android, and if it returns true, the function automatically add the "android_asset/www/". But in my case, the images for the volume slider's style are added in the CSS, so I can't call the js function.

So, how can I fix it? How to add "android_asset/www/" to the image's path in the CSS only if it is running in Android? Is there a way to call the js function in CSS? Is it possible to change the image's path in CSS from the html?

This is the js function's code:

**app.js**

```
$scope.convertAndroid = function(src){
        if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") { src = "/android_asset/www" + src; }
        return src;
};
```

And this is how I invoke the function in the html

**index.html**

```
 <img src={{convertAndroid('/img/something.png')}}>
```

Comment: Just modify the function to change the backgound-image-url for the element?

Comment: While it might be technically possible to do it the way you propose, I do not think it is best practice. It would be better to consider using gulp or grunt to pre compile to CSS based on your build target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a mistake in the general concept here. A hybrid application creates separate WWW folders for each platform, i.e. web, Android, IOS, etc. For example, following is the general hierarchy:

```
root project
----wwww
--------platforms
------------android
----------------assets
--------------------www
------------ios
```

It means that, every platform sees the related WWW folder as the root directory. If you are running on Android, it will read the WWW inside assets. You just have to create the same content for every WWW folder in your project.

Comment: That's right. If you run the app on Android, the root directory will be **android/assets/www** instead of **www**. So, as long as the content of www is same, your image path should be valid. For example, your path is **/img/slider.png**. On web, this will point to **www/img/slider.png**, and on Android, this will point to **assets/www/img/slider.png**

Comment: When I add an image to the www folder, it automatically adds the image to the www folder inside the android/assets. And even with the images inside the android/assets, when I run the app in Android it doesn't work, I still have to add "android_asset/www/" to the image's path.
And in my project, this is the hierarchy: rootproject/platforms/android/assets/www. the platforms folder isn't inside the rootproject/www

Comment: Are you running it as an application (.apk), or on a mobile browser?

Comment: I'm running it in the device.

Comment: Oh, I found the solution. I really don't need to add "android_asset/www/" in the path, I just needed to add "../", like this: **background-image: url("../img/slider.png")**. Now it's working in browser and in the device. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad you solved! Hope the concept is clear, that you don't need to do separate operations on each platform, which hybrid frameworks already do.